# How to decode a character with numeric character references in it

Tags: r

An external utility that I use encodes strings using numeric character references for non-ASCII characters. For instances it writes "`L&#205;NEA`" instead of "`LÍNEA`". I am reading files created by this external utility and would like to be able to convert the things it writes with encoded characters into a non encoded format.

So given

```
char = "L&#205;NEA"
char2 = "LÍNEA"
```

How do I modify `char` so that

```
char == char2
[1] TRUE
```

For any possible encoded character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `intToUtf8` to convert from an integer to a `UTF8` character in R, the problem is finding them and changing them in the string. To do this, I've made a function that uses regex to find these numeric characters, converts them to `UTF8` with `intToUtf8`, then uses `str_replace` to replace the numeric character with the proper `UTF8` character:

```
sub_utf8 <- function(char) {
    library(stringr)
    while(TRUE) {
        utf <- str_match(char, '\\&\\#([0-9]+)\\;')[,2]
        if (is.na(utf)) break()
        char <- sub('\\&\\#([0-9]+)\\;', intToUtf8(utf), char)
    }
    return(char)
}

char = "L&#205;NEA"
char2 = "LÍNEA"

sub_utf8(char)
[1] "LÍNEA"
sub_utf8(char) == char2
[1] TRUE
```

Because of the `while` loop, it will also work if there are multiple numeric `UTF8` characters:

```
char3 = "L&#205;NE&#100;A"
sub_utf8(char3)
[1] "LÍNEdA"
```

Note that this requires the package `stringr` because none of the base R regex options (as far as I know) properly support matching groups. If necessary, `str_match` could be replaced with calls to `regexec` to find the match, `regmatches` to extract the match, and `gsub` to remove the non-integer characters (ie. the `&#...;`) to properly get the `UTF8` integer value.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is just by looking at the text you have. All the elements are similar apart from `$#205;` I do not know why it did this yet, but in there you will find the ASCII code for `Í` which is `205`. If you do not know the ASCII code use `utf8ToInt('a')` function. Now for your problem:

```
iconv(sub("&#205;",intToUtf8(205),char1),'utf-8','utf8') ==char2
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the answer of @divibisan for my use case but came across a problem when processing surrogate pairs such as emoji characters. My solution was to process the characters in chunks instead of one by one. So any encoded character that is next to each other is processed together with `allow_surrogate_pairs=TRUE` in the `intToUttf8` function

```r
sub_decimal <- function(char){
  while(TRUE){
    # first get the character. might be in multipart
    utf <- stringr::str_extract(char, '(\\&\\#([0-9]+)\\;)+')
    if(is.na(utf)){
      break()
    }
    utf <- stringr::str_extract_all(utf,'[0-9]+')[[1]]
    char <- sub('(\\&\\#([0-9]+)\\;)+', intToUtf8(utf,allow_surrogate_pairs = TRUE), char)
  }
  return(char)
}
```